# creating new model field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

so lately I have had a model *customer.js* which had following fields:

```
   const customer = new schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    age:Number,
    });
```

now after few months I have added new field their *description*. My question is if I move this new model to the production. How will it effect my previous model and the customers who were created using old model? I am afraid if I move this new to production it will throw error `description undefined` in the UI console becuase old customers had no such field description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid breaking things:

1. Update your schema with the new `description` field:

```
const customer = new schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  age: Number,
  description: String,
});
```

2. Run a `db.collection.update(...)` to ensure you don't break things and every customer has the same schema:

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  { description: { $exists: false } } // All the customers without a description
  { $set: { description: '' } } // Set the description field to an empty string
)
```

Comment: Great. I was looking for exactly something similar